# Protractor : browser.get() doesn't function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, protractor-net

I am a newbie using protractor for angularjs app e2e testing.
I have the latest version of protractor setup and using Visual studio 2015 as the IDE.

The function browser.get() mentioned in my tests doesn't work and only opens up a browser window with "Data:,".

Here is my config.js file :

```
'use strict';
exports.config = {
        directConnect: true,
        chromeDriver: './node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver.exe',

    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'

    },

    // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
    // protractor is called.
    specs: ['example_spec.js'],
    framework: 'jasmine',

    // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    },

    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
};
```

Here is my spec.js file :

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function () {
    it('should have a title', function () {
      browser.get('http://angularjs.org/');

        expect(browser.getTitle()).toContain('AngularJS');
    });
});
```

Am i missing out on anything? Please help! i have been trying to fix this since 3 days now.

Comment: What version of chromedriver are you using?

Comment: I am using Chromedriver 2.21  @TesterPhi and no i am not using karma Riyaj!

Comment: If you're using protractor 3.0+, set your framework to 'jasmine2'

Comment: Tried with jasmine2, Still didn't work :( @martin770

Comment: Please tell me your node and protractor version.

Comment: One more thing to add : the same tests can be executed successfully in node.js console however the problem occurs only in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

The  first thing,

```
chromeDriver: './node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver.exe'
```

is not needed.Your web-driver manager manage it.

```
If your protractor version is >3.0  then install node > 4.0.
```

UPDATE :

Please fire following command :

```
webdriver-manager update
```

Comment: Node >4.0 ? you mean i need to upgrade my npm package? @RIYAJ KHAN

Comment: Please tell me node and protractor version

Comment: Node.js version is 4.2.2 and protractor version is 3.1.1

Comment: I do not get any error as such,I am running the tests directly from Visual studio, the browser is launched with data;, in it and browser.get() is not getting hit.

Comment: I have run your script as it is except chromedriver change and it working fine for me.Please check VS docs for proractor.

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sample-for-Testing-d2200bc5/sourcecode?fileId=108145&pathId=1697759612

Comment: Got this fixed! i had to update my node.js version from 4.6.2 to 5.4.0. Thanks to all for your support!